# Deploy Angular SSR project to cpanel (GoDaddy server)

Tags: angular, apache, cpanel, server-side-rendering, angular-service-worker

I've done an **Angular 8** project on my localhost following this link:

[Server Side rendering with Angular universal 8](https://www.ganatan.com/tutorials/server-side-rendering-with-angular-universal)

This command builds and generates files in both browser and server, and the project runs on http://localhost:4200

`npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr`

**Is it possible to run deploy this project on cpanel (with SSR enabled)?**

I've deployed normal Angular projects on cpanel in the past by copy pasting the content of dist folder.
Just wanna know if it's possible to do the same for SSR, with no Node.js installed on my godaddy server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to SSH on your server ?

Comment: The command you specific above specifically depends on node being available to execute. Are you indicating you cannot have node installed on your hosting solution?

Comment: I used those commands to generate build files on localhost within browser and server folders. When I run on localhost, it's working fine. But the live server is godaddy shared server, so I don't have shell access.

Comment: I know the angular *dist* folder contents can be uploaded via ftp and run on live site. But is it possible somehow to do the same with SSR related files?

Comment: To run dynamic SSR you need NodeJS or .NET core. If you cannot install either on your hosting solution nor do you have shell access, you probably will not be able to use Angular Universal. This is a common limitation of shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided by angular itself [here](https://angular.io/guide/universal), you can not run SSR (server-side rendering) without nodejs being enabled in your cPanel account or any web server that can interact with `renderModule()` which nodejs seemed to be perfect on. However, you can easily install nodejs on your cPanel by following this guide provided by cPanel: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/ though, you will need SSH access to your server. You can contact your hosting provider if you don't know your SSH details.